# How to Make a "for loop" Recursive

Tags: bash, loops, terminal

I have a command that seems to successfully replace double quotes (") with single quotes (') for filenames within the current directory. However, I need to do this recursively (i.e., all files within all subdirectories). Here is the code I am working with:

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        new_name=$(echo "$f" | sed "s/\"/'/g")
        mv "$f" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Safer to use `find -execdir` to do this so your directories don't get swapped out with symlinks during operation. Adding an answer, justaminute...

Comment: (btw, better to avoid `echo "...anything..." | sed` when you can avoid it; starting an external program or a shell pipeline is expensive compared to just doing string manipulation internal to bash -- if your filesystem settings allow flush-to-disk to be deferred, that probably costs more time than running `mv` does; see [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and/or the bash-hackers page on [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for alternatives).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice (and the much more efficient solution when you're dealing with a large and deeply-nested directory tree) is to use `find` for this, not a `for` loop in bash at all. [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) goes into the tradeoffs between `-print0`, `-exec` and `-execdir`; here, I'm using the last of these:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# define the function we're going to export for access from a subprocess
do_replace() {
  local name new_name old_quotes='"' new_quotes="'"
  for name do  # loops by default over "$@", the argument list given to the function
    new_name=${name//$old_quotes/$new_quotes}
    mv -- "$name" "$new_name"
  done
}
export -f do_replace # actually export that function

# tell find to start a new copy of bash that can run the function we exported
# in each directory that contains one or more file or directory names with quotes.
# Using ``-execdir ... {} ';'`` to work around a MacOS bug
# ...use ``-execdir ... {} +`` instead with GNU find for better performance.
find . -depth -name '*"*' -execdir bash -c 'do_replace "$@"' _ {} ';'
```

That way there's a new copy of bash for each directory, so you aren't operating on names with `/`s in them; this avoids some security holes that can happen if you're renaming files in directories a different user can write to.

---

That said, the *easy* thing (in bash 4.0 or later) is to enable `globstar`, after which `**` will recurse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# WARNING: This calculates the whole glob before it runs any renames; this can be very
# inefficient in a large directory tree.

case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac
shopt -s globstar
for f in **; do
  : "put your loop's content here as usual"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Charles! I am on Bash 5.0.11(1)-release. However, I'm not sure exactly how to run these commands. Are they meant to be run via several separate commands? And with the globstar approach, how would it look with my loop's content in there? Do I keep the colon, for example, in front of "put your loop's content here..."? So far, I seem to be getting some results, but nothing recursive.

Comment: The colon is like `true` -- it's a conventional placeholder. I used it because an empty loop body is invalid syntax. Replace the whole body of the loop.

Comment: I'm not really clear what the question (about "exactly how to run these commands") is. The first example should be something you can either put in a script to have a runnable executable, *or* run manually one command at a time.

Comment: @LivingMiracles, ...do the comments that have been added help? I also fixed a bug caused by the `old_quotes` and `new_quotes` variables not being exported (moving them into the function means they don't need to be).

Comment: What does the `_` in `bash -c 'do_replace "$@"' _ {}` do?

Comment: Ok, yes the comments definitely help! I'm attempting the "find" command (with the new edits) but am getting a lot of these type of errors: mv: rename test"file.txt to test'file.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: The `_` is a placeholder for `$0`, so subsequent values go into `$1` and onward.

Comment: Hmm. Could you change the `bash -c` to `bash -xc`? That'll give us a log of commands being run. And maybe add something like `: Running in "$PWD"` as a line in the function before it starts the `for` loop, so the `-x` logs will tell us which directory each invocation is for (so we can figure out what a correct `mv` looks like in that directory, and can compare it to the ones in those logs).

Comment: Here is a link to the -xc output: https://gist.github.com/jasonpress/fe2902b41cb5169eb307a08b7a2c6bb6

Comment: ...okay, I can reproduce that locally. Going to try to puzzle it out.

Comment: Okay, got it; bug with the version of `find` that MacOS ships. If you can't upgrade to a modern GNU findutils version (4.7.0 definitely doesn't have the bug), then we'll want to switch from `-execdir ... {} +` to (slower) `-execdir ... {} ';'`.

Comment: Thanks Charles, that did indeed do the trick! Appreciate the patience and fast responses!!