# How to get bash find exec to directly execute commands instead of using a temp file?

Tags: bash, find, sh, refactoring, exec

I've written this BASH script:

```
find ./build/html -name '*.html' \( -exec echo ../emojize_pngorsvg.py \"{}\" \> \"{}.emojized\" \&\& rm \"{}\" \&\& mv \"{}.emojized\" \"{}\" >> ../emojize_commands.sh \; \)
cat ../emojize_commands.sh
chmod +x ../emojize_commands.sh
../emojize_commands.sh
```

It loops over all of the HTML files it finds in the `./build/html` dir and it creates a single file called `emojize_commands.sh` which looks something like this:

```
../emojize_pngorsvg.py "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Force-activate-a-Windows-evaluation/index.html" > "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Force-activate-a-Windows-evaluation/index.html.emojized" && rm "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Force-activate-a-Windows-evaluation/index.html" && mv "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Force-activate-a-Windows-evaluation/index.html.emojized" "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Force-activate-a-Windows-evaluation/index.html"
../emojize_pngorsvg.py "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Various-Windows-Tips/index.html" > "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Various-Windows-Tips/index.html.emojized" && rm "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Various-Windows-Tips/index.html" && mv "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Various-Windows-Tips/index.html.emojized" "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Various-Windows-Tips/index.html"
../emojize_pngorsvg.py "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html" > "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html.emojized" && rm "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html" && mv "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html.emojized" "./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html"
# Much more lines here
```

Then it executes `emojize_commands.sh` - which works perfectly as expected!

I'm trying to remove the need for it to use a temporary file to do all of this. I'd rather it just execute the commands directly instead of needing to `echo` them to a file first.

I've tried removing `echo` and `>> ../emojize_commands.sh` (plus all of the other lines of code) so I am left with just this:

```
find ./build/html -name '*.html' \( -exec ../emojize_pngorsvg.py \"{}\" \> \"{}.emojized\" \&\& rm \"{}\" \&\& mv \"{}.emojized\" \"{}\" \; \)
```

But when I run it I get a bunch of "file not found" errors!

How can I get `find` to work how I want please?

Comment: `for f in build/html/*.html; do ../emojize_pnhorsvg.py "$f" > "$f.emojized" && rm "$f" && mv "$f.emojized" "$f"; done` ?

Comment: if you really want find: `find build/html -name '*.html' -exec bash -c 'for f; do ../emojize_pnhorsvg.py "$f" > "$f.emojized" && rm "$f" && mv "$f.emojized" "$f"; done' -- {} +`

Comment: generally, quoting strings is error-prone - for example,  `\&\&` is not being interpreted as you intended (see description of `-exec` option behaviour)

Comment: @jhnc Perhaps you could post an answer? 

Comment: @jhnc I like the simplicity of the `for` in your 1st comment, but it doesn't seem to be recursive? Only `./build/html/index.html.emojized` is created. All other files are not created, E.G. `./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html.emojized` is not created.

Comment: yes, I misinterpreted `-name '*.html'`. for recursion, `find` is useful; although bash allows `shopt -s globstar` / `for f in build/html/**/*.html; ...`

Comment: Why not parallelise?

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I hadn't considered that! This is part of a larger `DOCKERFILE`, I need to wait for this block to finish executing before it moves on to the next block (not posted here) as it is creating a Docker container. Is it possible to make a blocking parallelization? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Under [tag:tash] yes, by using `wait -p`, I'v posted some samples, [search for *`maxProx`* in my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1765658+maxProc)

Comment: Lookup the `sponge`  tool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could have the `-exec` run each line via `bash -c` instead of `echo`ing it to a file to be run later.  That would also enable (require, in fact) adjusting your quoting, ultimately allowing a simpler and clearer command.  For example:

```
find ./build/html -name '*.html' \
  -exec bash -c '../emojize_pngorsvg.py "{}" > "{}.emojized" && mv "{}.emojized" "{}"' \;
```

I took the liberty of some additional simplification, too.  Specifically, it is unnecessary to remove the original file before `mv`ing the new one to the original name.  Also, the `\(` and `\)` in the original command served no useful purpose, so I dropped them.

Also, I generally pipe `find`'s output into `xargs` instead of using an `-exec` action.  You could consider that, but it probably does not provide enough advantage in this case to justify the conversion.

Comment: quoted strings are dangerous: `touch 'build/html/"; echo oops; : "'`

Comment: @jhnc `${file}` seems to be a nicer choice than `"$file"` - are there any drawbacks to it? I get what you're saying about sanitization. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBeckett I don't see either in this code. Using `${var}` or `$var` is a matter of taste unless it could be misparsed (eg. `$var2` / `${var}2`).  Sometimes `${...}` is more legible. `${...}` is [computationally more expensive](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb/subst.c#L8751) but not by enough to make any practical difference.

Comment: @jhnc Ah sorry, you were referring to the double-quotes inside the single-quotes of this answer being dangerous? Thank you for your advice on `${var}` nonetheless, I appreciate it!

Comment: @DannyBeckett you need double-quotes to avoid potential wordsplitting (eg. `a='x   y'; echo "$a"; echo $a`), but I was referring to [string interpolation across semantic domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77951042/10971581)

Comment: @jhnc, yes, it is tricky to avoid the possibility that file names containing single or double quote characters would break something like the alternative presented in this answer.  This answer is aimed at the question as posed: how to do this [possibly unsafe] thing without generating a temporary script file.  If you would like to offer an answer suggesting that the OP instead do something different and more robust then you are welcome to do so.

Comment: someone already did :-)

Comment: @DannyBeckett, note well that the side discussion between jhnc and me in these comments was about cases where the provided quoting was *not enough*.  The quotes around the overall input to `bash -c` are essential.  The quotes within around appearances of `{}` might or might not be required, depending on the file names in your data.  It would be a little better, though, to swap the quotes: double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside, around each appearance of `{}`.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' \;)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#find_._-exec_sh_-c_.27echo_.7B.7D.27_.2BAFw.3B).

Answer (score 3):

Spawn a shell and run those commands there.

```
find ./build/html -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
for f; do
  ../emojize_pngorsvg.py "$f" >"$f.emojized" &&
  mv "$f.emojized" "$f"
done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Or even you could: `find ./build/html -type f -name '*.html' -printf '../emojize_pngorsvg.py "%p" >"%p.emojized" && mv "%p.emojized" "%p"\n'` for see, then `| sh`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about adding a 2nd loop in to the mix

Comment: @DannyBeckett, this is the only answer posted so far that works correctly for all possible filenames.  If you don't like the loop then you can remove it with: `find ./build/html -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '../emojize_pngorsvg.py "$1" >"$1.emojized" && mv "$1.emojized" "$1"' sh {} \;` .  All of the quotes are required.  Correct use of quotes is essential for writing reliable Bash, or POSIX shell, code.  See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/264812).

Answer (score 1):

## My chosen solution

I have ended up using and accepting [@John Bollinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78056481/1563422), which I ran through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and modified to account for [SC2156 (insecure variable injection)](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2156). The command iterates over the files only once and is easy to understand:

`find ./build/html -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '../emojize_pngorsvg.py "$1" > "$1.emojized" && mv "$1.emojized" "$1"' sh {} \;`

---

## Other solutions

I also like this which is basically [@jhnc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056195/how-to-get-bash-find-exec-to-directly-execute-commands-instead-of-using-a-temp-f/78057241#comment137607891_78056195):

`find ./build/html -name '*.html' -exec bash -c 'for f; do ../emojize_pngorsvg.py ${f} > ${f}.emojized && mv ${f}.emojized ${f}; done' -- {} +`

It differs in that it uses `${f}` instead of `"$f"`.

However I'm not sure what to think of the 2nd loop that has been introduced (now a `for` as well as a `find`) - similarly for [@oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78056407/1563422).

---

An alternative option could've been a `for` instead of a `find`, but unfortunately this does **not** support dir tree recursion.

---

I decided against using [@jhnc's other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056195/how-to-get-bash-find-exec-to-directly-execute-commands-instead-of-using-a-temp-f/78057241#comment137608774_78056195) of `shopt -s globstar` + `for f in build/html/**/*.html; ...` based upon [an unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884666/1563422) which warns that using `glob` can be slow with large dir trees - although it would seem that some performance testing is needed here, as it appears to be a gray area.

---

I didn't look into the parallelization solutions suggested [@F. Hauri - Give Up GitHub's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056195/how-to-get-bash-find-exec-to-directly-execute-commands-instead-of-using-a-temp-f/78057241#comment137609011_78056195), but it does appear to be possible to use with my own use-case of this being part of a large `DOCKERFILE` container creation script, and it needing to block the thread until execution completes.

---

[@ikegami's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056195/how-to-get-bash-find-exec-to-directly-execute-commands-instead-of-using-a-temp-f/78057241#comment137609055_78056195) presents another possible way to redirect output, but I didn't have time to try it this time unfortunately.

---

## Community

Please feel free to correct anything I may have misunderstood or not considered! Thank you very much to all who posted.

Comment: You seem confused about the use of quotes and `{...}`. Quotes aren't something to be avoided, they should be used around all strings, scripts and variables by default and only removed when you **need** to removed them, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Regarding `Except it uses ${f} instead of "$f", to avoid using quotes.` - `${f}` does absolutely nothing different than `$f`, it leaves the variable exposed to the shell for globbing, filename expansion, word splitting, etc., it should in no way be considered a possible substitute for quotes.

Comment: Did you try this: `find ./build/html -type f -name '*.html' -printf '../emojize_pngorsvg.py "%p" >"%p.emojized" && mv "%p.emojized" "%p"\n'` for see, then  same `... | sh` or better: `... | sh -v` ??

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' \;)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#find_._-exec_sh_-c_.27echo_.7B.7D.27_.2BAFw.3B).

Comment: `find ... -exec bash -c '...' -- {} \;` calls bash once for every match; `find ... -exec bash -c 'for f ...' -- {} +` calls bash on many files at once, which is a bit more efficient, and so requires the loop in order to process individual files. if the commands inside the bash script are computationally expensive, the efficiency gain becomes less significant, so the first version may be cleaner

Answer (score -2):

Since you already know where the repository is and which type of file you are looking for, the use of `find` is not optimal. you could simply use a for loop instead:

```
for file in ./build/html/*.html;do python ../emojize_pngorsvg.py "${file}" > "${file}.emojized"; mv "${file}.emojized" "${file}"; done;
```

Comment: Avoiding `find` altogether is a good idea (+1), but you must not redirect the output of `../emojize_pngorsvg.py` directly to the input file.    There are at least two problems with that: (1) the file will be truncated before the emojize script has a chance even to open it, much less read it; (2) even if it were not truncated, the file could be corrupted if the command crashed before fully writing the replacement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is exactly what I observed too when I tried redirecting the output to the input file - the files end up having their contents erased. This is why I used the `rm` + `mv`, but I wasn't aware I could just use `mv` by itself, like in your answer - thanks! 

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be recursive? If I change it to `${file} > ${file}.emojized` then only `./build/html/index.html.emojized` is created. All other files are not created, E.G. `./build/html/Home/Technical/Guides/Windows/Configure-RDP-to-connect-with-stored-credentials/index.html.emojized` is not created.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can I ask why avoiding `find` is a good idea please? Many thanks!

Comment: @DannyBeckett, its not that `find` is bad.  It's that if a glob pattern does the same job then the glob is usually superior: lighter weight, easier to understand, easier to write and maintain.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Readability & maintainability makes senses. On the subject of performance, I was reading [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884666/1563422) and it says *WARNING: This calculates the whole glob before it runs any renames; this can be very inefficient in a large directory tree.* - is this the **usually** part of your comment, ref lighterweight? How large is a large tree? Thanks again!

Comment: @DannyBeckett, it's unclear to me what that warning is about.  I suspect that when it says "very inefficient" it means "very *slow*", which is not the same thing. I'm skeptical about the proposition that matching a pattern against a whole tree at once (using `globstar` and `**`) is at risk of being substantially more costly than the aggregate of matching an analogous pattern against the contents of each directory in the tree individually.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code (missing quotes).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.